# How to update a column only once in a SQL Server Agent job that runs every 5 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to run this code only once in an agent job that gets hit every 5 minutes:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET text_column = (CONCAT('Added text - ', text_column))
WHERE status IN ('status1', 'status2', 'status3')
  AND other_criteria IN ('other_criteria1', 'other_criteria2', 'other_criteria3');
```

New records may get inserted any time of day and night - which is why the job runs every 5 min.

`text_column` may or may not be NULL when the record is inserted (which doesn't matter but, prevents me from using ISNULL in my where clause.)

`status` may change on the fly before the job runs (which also doesn't matter except that I cannot update the above query to only run against those specified statuses and then change the status after to ensure that the update doesn't happen again [because other transactions may still need to happen while the record is in whatever status].)

`other_criteria` is generally static information but, it is by no means unique...

So, what I want to happen is basically:

5 minute job runs - the new record = status1 & other_criteria1 gets the text_column set to 'Added_text - (text_column)'

Then I want to avoid having this record's text column set to 'Added text - Added text - (text_column)' the next time the job runs even when it still matches the "status" and "other_criteria" in my where clause...

Is this possible without getting more specific in my where clause?

Comment: use trigger instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to filter out added text:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET text_column=(CONCAT('Added text - ', text_column))
WHERE status IN ('status1', 'status2', 'status3')
AND other_criteria IN ('other_criteria1', 'other_criteria2', 'other_criteria3')
AND text_column NOT LIKE 'Added text - %';
```

Answer (score 2):

I would introduce one more column to your table

```
alter yourtable add column WasUpdated smallint default 0
```

Then add one more simple clause to your statement. A new record will have this set to zero and after first update set to 1, so one row will be updated only once.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET text_column=(CONCAT('Added text - ', text_column))
    ,wasUpdated = 1
WHERE status
IN ('status1', 'status2', 'status3')
AND other_criteria
IN ('other_criteria1', 'other_criteria2', 'other_criteria3')
AND wasUpdated = 0;
```

Such column won't introduce any headache, unless you have `select * from` in your procedures etc.

As Vitaly Borisov sugested you can also create a date column. With this approach you will know exactly when a row was updated.

```
  alter yourtable add column Updateddate datetime2 

    UPDATE mytable
    SET text_column=(CONCAT('Added text - ', text_column))
        ,Updateddate = getdate()
    WHERE status
    IN ('status1', 'status2', 'status3')
    AND other_criteria
    IN ('other_criteria1', 'other_criteria2', 'other_criteria3')
    AND Updateddate  is null;
Such column won't introduce any headache, unless you have `select * from` in your procedures etc.
```

Comment: Agree, but I'd go with Datetime2 WhenUpdated flag - so logic can be based on time, not just a fact it was updated.

Comment: Sure, it can be done your way too. Surely, your solution has a benefit regarding checking the data i.e. when rows were updated etc.